# Google Maps API, This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key with JIO SIM in India

Tags: android, google-maps

I have already gone through multiple answers, I'm already using server key, most of my Android devices are getting responses from Google Maps without any error. But with few Reliance JIO devices, I'm getting the below error.

This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx::xxx:xxxx, with empty referer

What could be the reason?

Comment: issue is not with JIO, when you create api in google console you add SHA key in console for that Key.but when you create Apk with different SHA key.

Comment: Would you mind providing more specific information about API that you use in your app. Is it Google Maps Android API, web services or hybrid app developed with Maps JavaScript API?